# JavaScript "str.replace()" not working/returning error

Tags: javascript, html, replace

This JavaScript:

```js
function renderTemplate() {
    var element = document.getElementById('code');
    var frame = document.getElementById('frame');
    var code = element.value;
    code = code.replace('&lt;', '<');
    code = code.replace('&gt;', '>');
  frame.srcdoc = code;
}
```

should replace every instance of "<" with "&lt" and replace ">" with "&gt".

But it returns

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at renderTemplate (/script.js:16:14)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:14:38)
```

What's wrong? (for source code, go [here](https://repl.it/@DabDatBass/stuff))

Comment: What type of element are you retrieving with your `getElementById('code')` call?

Comment: A value of a <pre> tag with edit mode on.

Comment: Not the problem causing the error quoted here, but you may like to look at your use of replace which will replace only the first instance of the string - is that what you want. Also you may have the two substrings the wrong way round if should replace every instance of "<" with "&lt" and replace ">" with "&gt" is right.

Comment: `<pre>` tags don't have a `value` attribute, you can use `innerHTML` to return the contained text. Per the docs: "This element only includes the [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes)."

Comment: Basically, replace `var code = element.value;` with `var code = element.innerHTML;` and in reference to A Haworth's comment you can use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a global flag if you want to replace all instances... `code = code.replace(/&lt;/g, '<');`

Comment: hey it works now i don't know what the heck happened tho